# Angular mat-table expand child rows - with the same columns

Tags: angular, pagination, expand, angular-material-table

I have to implement a table that has all the basic functionalities: sorting, pagination, filter, column width change (by drag an drop), column order change (by drag and drop).
Besides these functionalities I need to also expand some rows, and here is where I'm stuck. A row, can have 0 or any number of children rows that have the same columns.

So far, I've found two solutions, both with downsizes:

1. the angular recommended way with adding a new row, in which I have the insert a new table component to display, like:

```
<!-- simple original row -->
<mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; let idx = dataIndex; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
  (click)="expandRow($event, row, idx)"
  [ngClass]="{'parent-expanded': row.expanded}">
</mat-row>

<!-- child row -->
<mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay; when: rowIsChild"
  class="child-row">
</mat-row>
```

2. changing the data source - on expand, find position of parent element, and insert children bellow. This was a little tricky but I was able insert the child rows and to treat all the sort / filter scenarios like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(rawData);
    this.dataSource.sortData = this.tableSortData.bind(this);
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.tableFilterData.bind(this);
  }

  expandedRow: IRow;
  expandRow(row: IRow) {
    const data = [...this.rawData];

    if (!data.children) {
      return;
    }

    if (row.id === this.row?.id) {
      this.setDataSource(data.filter((dataItem) => !dataItem.parentId));
      this.expandedRow = undefined;
      return
    }

    const rowIndex = data.findIndex((dataItem) => dataItem.id === row.id);
    data.splice((rowIndex + 1), 0, ...row.children)

    this.setDataSource(data);
    this.expandedRow = row;
  }
```

Unfortunately for me, both solutions have missing pieces:

For the first solution I will have to create a new component (which I do not quite want), and most important, the connection (for resize, reorder) between the parent and child columns will be lost

For the second solution, though I was able to bypass most of the encountered issues, there is one huge issue - the pagination. For instance let's consider the following:

- we have data paginated with 5 elements on a page
- the parent is the 4th element on the 2nd page and has 3 children.
- on expand, only the first child will be rendered on the current page, the rest of the children will be on the next page.

I was thinking that I could change the number of elements displayed on a page, so all the children to fit, but I would have to find a safe algorithm to determine the number of elements on the page and the actual page number to render the parent and all the children on the same page, then I would, probably, have to scroll the table to the elements. A lot of moving pieces, and probably there are some other potential issues that I cannot see right now.

So my questions are, is there a simpler manner to achieve this that I have overseen? or is there a way that I could update the existent solutions to work? like:
for the first solution to make that child row template to replicate for each child row but to still be ignored by the pagination?
or, for the second solution, to make, somehow, some rows to be ignored from pagination?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: mat-table is just a table, it was not design to do what you're trying to achieve, what you're looking for is called tree table. PrimeNg have a component for TreeTable and you can just use their material theme design. https://primeng.org/treetable

Comment: This is pretty similar with what I'm trying to get; unfortunately, at this point, an external package is not an option.. Also, I totally agree that mat-table, by design, is not made for this type of edge case requirements, but I was hoping that maybe there's a trick or a not-so-obvious feature that I could make use of :)